# Multipass: How do you select a different image than the default?

Tags: multipass

I'm trying to setup a VM using Multipass, and I want to select the "docker" image instead of the default.

I've seen the documentation at https://multipass.run/docs/launch-command, which at the bottom has:

```
image                Optional image to launch. If omitted, then the default
                     Ubuntu LTS will be used.
                     <remote> can be either ‘release’ or ‘daily‘. If <remote>
                     is omitted, ‘release’ will be used.
                     <image> can be a partial image hash or an Ubuntu release
                     version, codename or alias.
                     <url> is a custom image URL that is in http://, https://,
                     or file:// format.
```

But I don't know what syntax I'm supposed to use to select an image.

`$ multipass launch --image docker` gives `Unknown option 'image'.`

`$ multipass launch image docker` gives `Too many arguments supplied`.

`$ multipass launch image=docker` gives `launch failed: Remote "" is unknown or unreachable.`

How do I create a VM with a different image than the default?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is `multipass launch docker`

- `image` is indeed an argument, but it's a variable. It's just the name of the VM. In this case, you want the default VM named 'docker'.
- If you customize and rename the VM to `shampoo`, then the syntax would be `multipass launch shampoo`

Source: https://ubuntu.com/blog/docker-on-mac-and-windows-multipass

Answer (score 0):

1. This will launch a docker image called docker

   `multipass launch docker`
2. This will launch a docker image called nHaskins-dockerVM

   `multipass launch docker --name nHaskins-dockerVM`
3. To see a list of available images, use

   `multipass find`

Source: I didn't find the solution anywhere, ran into your unanswered problem, figured it out, and thought someone else might run into this again